# Don't allow additional added images to be added after maximum is reached (dropzonejs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm working on some modifications to the `dropzonejs` image uploader. I want to allow a maximum of 12 image uploads. I see the config for `maxFiles`, but after setting this to 12 it still allows files to  be added and generates thumbnail previews. Is there are way to modify, so once the limit of 12 is reached it will no longer generate a thumbnail or add the files to the upload list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dropzone [`maxfilesexceeded`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-maxfilesexceeded) event, that triggers for every file rejected for exced the limit, to remove this files:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    maxFiles: 12,
    init: function() {
        this.on('maxfilesexceeded', function(file){
            this.removeFile(file);
        });
    }
};
```